# Why reply variable is giving index number of greetReply array? I want the value from that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var value = document.getElementById("value");

var greeting = ['hi', 'hello', 'Hlw', 'hello jii', 'hey', 'helo', 'hi there', 'hey']
var greetReply = ['hlw', 'kisu na', 'gaan shuni'];


submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const reply = Math.floor(Math.random() * greetReply.length); // random reply!

    for (let i = 0; i < greeting.length; i++) {
        if(value.value === greeting[i]){
            console.log(reply)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to access the value of the array by the index number, try to modify this line:

```js
console.log(greetReply[reply])
```

Answer (score 1):

reply is a random index from `greetReply` to get value of that index use it
this way `greetReply[reply]`